# Why is BlockingQueue.take() not releasing the thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In this simple short program, you will notice that the program hangs forever because the take() does not release the thread. According to my understanding, take() causes the thread to be released even though the task itself is blocked on take().

Edited:

This works (thanks to you all for fixing the autoboxing):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ProducersConsumers {
    private static int THREAD_COUNT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService executorPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        final LinkedBlockingQueue<Long> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Long>();

        Collection<Future<Long>> collection = new ArrayList<Future<Long>>();


        // producer:
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            collection.add(executorPool.submit(new Callable<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long call() throws Exception {
                    for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
                        queue.put((long) i);
                    }
                    return -1L;
                }
            }));
        }

        // consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            collection.add(executorPool.submit(new Callable<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long call() throws Exception {
                    while (true) {
                        Long item = queue.take();
                        if (item.intValue() == 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return 1L;
                }
            }));
        }

        long sum = 0;
        for (Future<Long> item : collection) {
            sum += item.get();
        }

        executorPool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

**But if you swap the producer and consumer invocations, it will hang:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class ProducersConsumers {
    private static int THREAD_COUNT = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        final ExecutorService executorPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_COUNT);
        final LinkedBlockingQueue<Long> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Long>();

        Collection<Future<Long>> collection = new ArrayList<Future<Long>>();


        // consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            collection.add(executorPool.submit(new Callable<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long call() throws Exception {
                    while (true) {
                        Long item = queue.take();
                        if (item.intValue() == 0) {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return 1L;
                }
            }));
        }

        // producer:
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            collection.add(executorPool.submit(new Callable<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long call() throws Exception {
                    for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
                        queue.put((long) i);
                    }
                    return -1L;
                }
            }));
        }

        long sum = 0;
        for (Future<Long> item : collection) {
            sum += item.get();
        }

        executorPool.shutdown();
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

To my understanding the producer and consumer order should not matter. In other words, there is a notion of task and thread. Thread are independent of code program whereas task is associated with a certain program. Therefore, in my example, when the JVM assigns a thread to execute of the Callable tasks, if the consumer is instantiated first, then the task will block on take(). Once the JVM discovers that the task is blocked, it will release the thread (or as I understand it but it is not releasing it) and places it back to the worker thread pool in preparation for processing a runnable task (which in this case are the Producers). Consequently, at the end of instantiating all the Callable's, there should be 40 tasks but only 5 threads; 20 of those tasks are blocked, 5 of the tasks should be running and 15 should be waiting (to run).

Comment: In this code the consumers will block until each one dequeues a "0" entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how threads and threadpools work. A threadpool typically has a work item queue which contains items to be worked on (in your case `Callable<>`s).

It also contains a (maximum) number of threads (in your case 5) which can work on those items.

The lifetime of an active thread is defined by the code it executes - usually a method. The thread becomes "alive" when it starts executing the method and it ends when it returns. If the method blocks to wait on some signal it does not mean the the thread can go away and execute some other method - that's not how threads work. Instead the thread will be blocked until it can continue execution and enable other threads to be run.

The method which is run by a threadpool thread usually looks like this:

```
void threadloop()
{
    while (!quit)
    {
        Callable<T> item = null;
        synchronized (workQueue)
        {
            if (workQueue.Count == 0)
                workQueue.wait();

            // we could have been woken up for some other reason so check again
            if (workQueue.Count > 0)
                item = workQueue.pop();
        }
        if (item != null)
             item.Call();
    }
}
```

This is more or less pseudo code (I'm not a Java developer) but it should show the concept. Now `item.Call()` executes the method which is supplied by the user of the pool. If that method blocks, then what happens? Well - the thread will be blocked in its execution of `item.Call()` until the method wakes up again. It can't just go away and execute some other code arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2):

From [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29):

*Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if no elements are present on this queue.*

It will wait: you're running in `main`, so it will stay there.

EDIT: correction: the blocking still happens (in the thread pool threads, not in `main`). There is no yielding going on: the 20 threads are blocked on the `take` calls, so no `put` calls execute, so the `Future`s never complete, so the program hangs.

Comment: No, it looks like he is submitting the consumers to an executor.

Comment: Correct, but same issue remains: the `take` calls block whatever thread they run in. In this case he has 20 `take` calls blocking 20 threads: the `put` calls never actually run, so the `Future`s never actually get completed, so it hangs.

Comment: First, thank you. Second, I have update the code. As I mentioned above, if I swap the instantiation of the producer and consumer, it will hang.

Comment: If you call `put` before `take` everything works as expected: no surprises there, as all the `take` calls will succeed. If you call `take` before `put` then it will hang: the `take` calls MUST block, as there is no `yield` concept implemented. `take` is EXPLICITLY blocking, as the javadoc says. Since all 20 threads are waiting, there are no threads to service the `put` calls, so nothing ever gets added to the queue, so none of the `take` calls ever succeed, so it hangs forever.

Comment: As long as there are less threads than `take` calls, this will block. If you make the THREAD_COUNT one more than the number of `take` calls, it will succeed.

Comment: Femi, I'll take your word for it but that seems very precarious. Then I would need to have two Executor pools, one for producers, and one for consumers to prevent this problem from happening.

Comment: Yes, you would, and nothing precarious about it: the spec for `take` captures the implemented behavior perfectly. You have to pay attention to your thread pools and make sure they are adequately sized for your workload. If you want to get into a philosophical debate about whether this is the optimal way to write multithreaded code then that's a separate question, but as far as the scenario you've outlined goes everything is performing as written.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you mean by `release thread` but once you block on `take()` the calling thread is blocked and is not going back to the pool.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood what gets "blocked" in a `BlockingQueue`.

The call to `queue.take()` blocks the thread that invoked it until something is available in the queue. This means that the thread will wait there endlessly, unless interrupted, until an item is added to the queue.

The second code sample hangs the problem because you are adding 20 tasks to wait for an item to appear in the `BlockingQueue`, and the executor has just 5 threads in it - thus the first five tasks cause all five of the threads to block. This executor is filled with 15 further consumer tasks.

The addition of tasks in the second for-loop to add items to the queue results in 20 tasks that can never be executed, because all threads in the executor are stuck waiting.

So when you say this:

> According to my understanding, take() causes the thread to be released even though the task itself is blocked on take().

You have a misunderstanding because there is no difference here between what the "thread" does and what the "task" does. A thread cannot be "released" while the task is blocked - it is the thread that runs the task. When the thread encounters a blocking call to `take()`, the thread is blocked, period.

Comment: I agree that is what I am witnessing, but if that is how the JVM developers did it, it would be a nightmare to develop multi-threading code because then I would have to submit the Callable's in a certain order (depending on whether I know they are ready to run or will be blocked), otherwise, the program will hang. That sounds horrible

Comment: Well, the JDK also offers non-blocking queues as well. You are correct though that (in most languages) multi-threaded code can be a pain for reasons along these lines.